# Spring MVC dropdown retain the value based on form action

Tags: spring, select, model-view-controller, conditional-statements, jstl

I have a JSP page with few submit buttons with in a Spring MVC application. It has few dropdown boxes and I need to retain the application predefined value (example, 'getInfo') for few submit button clicks ('btnSelectAll', 'btnUnselectAll'), and need to retain the user selected values (other than 'getInfo') for other few submit button clicks ('defaultAction', 'btnReset').

Created a (hidden, modelattribute) variable 'buttonClicked' which captures the value of button action the user has selected. For example 'defaultAction', 'btnReset', and i able to see the user selected button value on JSP page.

```
<form:select path = "user.action" multiple="false" >
    <c:forEach items="${actions}" var="role">
         <option value="${role}" ${(role eq 'getInfo' and (buttonClicked eq 'defaultAction' or buttonClicked eq 'btnReset')) ? 'selected' : ''}>${role}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

Added the above JSTL logic to validate the iterated value equal to 'getInfo' and using along with buttonClicked variable for the solution. But, for some reason I 'm not able to use the buttonClicked value for conditional operations within JSTL foreach.

Can someone point out what i'm doing wrong. Or if some other better solution or links, please share.

I spend a good amount of time, thanks in advance.

Thank you,
Ramesh

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this using javascript. you can assign the value of `buttonClicked` to a javascript variable and set the value in the dropdown based on the conditions

```
<form:select path = "user.action" multiple="false" >
    <c:forEach items="${actions}" var="role">
         <option value="${role}">${role}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
...
<script>
      var buttonClicked = <c:out value="${buttonClicked}"/>
      var roleObj = document.getElementById('<dropdown id>');
      setValue(roleObj,'getInfo'); 
      function setValue(selectObj, valueToSet) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
          if (selectObj.options[i].text== valueToSet
              && (buttonClicked == 'defaultAction' || buttonClicked == 'btnReset' )) {
            selectObj.options[i].selected = true;
             return;
           }
        }
      } 
</script>
```